# Working principle of the AD8232 high pass filter

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, datasheet, high-pass-filter, ecg

[This is the datasheet of the AD8232.](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8232.pdf)

On page 22 in the section  "Additional High-Pass Filtering Options" is this diagram:

[image: Figure 56]

It is said that the cut off frequency is located at

[image]

I tried to find out where this formula came from.

I tried to make the equivalent circuit of this filter in hopes I could find the transfer function of this circuit.

What I get is not in accordance with the high pass filter circuit and looks like a low pass filter:

[image]

I would be happy if someone could explain to me how to get the cut off frequency and equivalent circuit of this high-pass filter.

EDIT: Thanks Andy Aka, so if there is a low-pass filter in the negative feedback of an amplifier the circuit performs as a high-pass? 
And I still don't know how to get the cut-off frequency formula.

As far as I know the formula for the cut off frequency is 
$$
fc=1/2\pi\sqrt(R1C1R2C2)
$$

Answer (score 1):

> HPSENSE - High-Pass Sense Input for Instrumentation Amplifier. Connect
>   HPSENSE to the junction of R and C that sets the corner frequency of
>   the dc blocking circuit.

HPSENSE is a negative feedback point for the instrumentation amplifier that processes the input and, if you connect the output of said IA to HPSENSE via a low pass filter (yes, that is what you analysed), the overall transfer function from the input of the IA to "the next stage" is one of a high pass filter.

> I would be happy if someone could explain me about how to get the cut
>   off frequency and equivalent circuit of this High-Pass Filter

It ***is*** a low pass filter but, due to it being in the negative feedback path of an amplifier, the whole circuit performs as a high pass filter.